# No response when typing "git remote -v"

Tags: git, github

I tried to edit a code from my local repository and tried to pull before pushing from my master branch.

I typed:

```
git pull RepositoryName master
```

It says:

```
fatal: 'RepositoryName' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What am I supposed to do here? I think the problem lies within the "git remote -v". Please help, I'm confused with git pushing and pulling

Comment: So what does `git remote -v` say?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I supposed to do here? I think the problem lies within the "git remote -v".

`git remote -v` just gives you a verbose listing of your remote repos. If that command doesn't give you any output, then you probably don't have any remote repos configured. I'm not sure how you got into that state if your local repo is a clone of some remote repo, but whatever the case, you'll need to add a remote before you can push or pull to it. Use `git remote add <RemoteName> <RemoteURL>` to add a remote.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the git origin alias by

```
$ git remote add origin URL_TO_YOUR_REPO
```

Then to push the existing local repo, type in

```
$ git push -u origin --all
```